# Math Fonts for Cochineal package

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, math-fonts

I like to use the `cochineal` font for my document, however for this font I understand there are no corresponding mathematical fonts. So I am asking if anyone knows of any font similar to `cochineal` that also supports math fonts or a math font similar to `cochineal` fonts.

I am using the `KOMAscript` class for the document.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `newtxmath` with the appropriate option.

Here's a modification of an answer to a question of yours.

Note that you should load neither `amssymb` nor `amsfonts`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\usepackage[english]{babel}


% ----------------------------
% STANDARD PACKAGES FOR MATH
% ----------------------------
\usepackage{amsmath}            % AMS Math Package
%\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}             % theorem formatting 

\usepackage{cochineal}
\usepackage[cochineal]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}                 % bold math

\theoremstyle{plain} % default
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}


\newcommand{\imag}{\mathtt{i}}  % imaginary number
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}% might also be \bm{#1}
\newcommand{\bC}{\mathbb{C}}
\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}
\newcommand{\bQ}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

T\textit{T}$T$ X\textit{X}$X$ a\textit{a}$a$

\begin{theorem}[Duffy, Pan and Singleton (2000)]
If $\vb{X}(t)$ is in the affine form, the discounted characteristic function defined as
\begin{equation}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(t),t,T) = \bE^{\bQ}
%  \left[
  \bigl[
    e^{-\int_{t}^{T} r(\vb{X}(s))\diff s + \imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)}
%  \;\middle|\;
  \bigm|
    \mathcal{F}_{t} 
%  \right]
  \bigr]
  \quad \forall \, \vb{u} \in \bC^{d},
\end{equation}
with boundary condition
\begin{equation}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),T,T) = e^{\imag \vb{u}^{T} \vb{X}(T)},
\end{equation}
has a solution of the following form
\begin{equation}\label{eq:AD_chf}
  \phi(\vb{u},\vb{X}(T),t,T) = e^{A(\vb{u},t,T) + \vb{B}(\vb{u},t,T)^{T} \vb{X}(t)}
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: bm after newtxmath I guess or bm will pick up cm fonts

Comment: For the example it's enough to load the single package `newtx` with `\usepackage[vvarbb,amsthm,cochineal]{newtx}`.  This also loads `amsmath` and `amsthm`.

Comment: @MátéWierdl I've seen recently a case where `newtx` behaves differently from the combination of the two packages.

Comment: @egreg Is there is a simple example which shows the difference?  Is there a quality difference?

Comment: @MátéWierdl Try the sans-serif font.

Comment: @egreg I see no difference.  In fact, in sans-serif fonts, loading of `cochineal` or `newtx*` packages seem to make no difference (I am using `article` class). I have 2022 february versions of the package (as they come on latest Fedora Linux)

Comment: On the other hand, you are right, @egreg, I did find a difference which can be considered a bug, IMO: the new `cochf` and `cochrho` options (which supposed to change the `f` and `\rho` in math mode) work only when `\usepackage[p,osf]{cochineal} \usepackage[cochf,cochrho,cochineal]{newtxmath}` but they do not work when only `\usepackage[cochf,cochrho,cochineal]{newtx}`

Answer (score 2):

One option might be Libertinus Math:

[image: Cochineal with Libertinus Math]

Comment: ok thank you, the argument you passed is "libertinust1math" ?

Comment: Honestly, I did that test file in ConTeXt, but you tagged the question `unicode-math`, so I guess you can use `\setmathfont`.